# nav bar is not wrapped when browser is iPad size, how to fix?

Tags: css, wordpress, navigation, navbar

I'm working on a site:
sites.northwestern.edu/mrsec

And when the browser becomes iPad size (1024 px), part of the navigation menu goes below the rest of the menu and for some reason it is not contained within the background color, and the font is white, so people can't see it. when the browser is made even small enough, the part of the menu that is below the rest is wrapped by the same background color (gray), but until then, people can't see the part of the menu that is below the rest of the menu. How can I fix this using CSS or any other language? I'm using a wordpress template, I don't have access to the php or template files because the school does not give us that access.

Comment: shirley you have an isolated and reproducible problem code snippet for us.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a media query to target the screen size you want then add a style to reduce padding and font-size so that every menu item gets displayed.

In your case it would look something like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
    .main-navigation a{
        padding: 0 15px;
        font-size:14px;
    }
}
```

See [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KeKn.jpg) of the result.